# M-S-<left> not processed as expected

Tags: emacs

When I start a new emacs in a terminal like so

```
emacs -nw -Q
```

I can try to check what a certain keyboard shortcut is bound to by typing <kbd>C-h k</kbd>. When I do this for the shortcut <kbd>M-S-<left></kbd> in the `*scratch*` buffer right after starting Emacs, I get:

> <M-left> runs the command left-word (found in global-map), which is an 
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘bindings.el’.
>
> It is bound to <C-left>, <M-left>.
>
> [...]

Note the absence of the "Shift" modifier in the recognized key sequence.

Now, the first instinct would be that the terminal (gnome-terminal in my case) does not produce the correct escape sequence, but it does: typing <kbd>CTRL-V ALT-SHIFT-left</kbd> in the terminal (i.e., not in Emacs) produces

```
^[[1;4D
```

and typing <kbd>C-q C-S-<left></kbd> inside Emacs inserts the same into  the current buffer. (Note that `^[` is a single character, namely ASCII 27 ("Escape").)

Checking `input-decode-map` reveals the following value (some parts left out (marked as `...`) for brevity):

```
(keymap
 (27 keymap ... )
 keymap
 (keymap
  (27 keymap
      ...
      (91 keymap
          ...
          (51 keymap
              ...
              (59 keymap
                  (51 keymap
                      ...
                      (68 .
                          [M-left])
                  (52 keymap
              ...
                      (68 .
                          [M-S-left])
                      ...)
                  ...)
              ...)
          ...))))
```

Verifying the two key sequences with the following code gives the expected results:

```lisp
(mapc '(lambda (c) (insert (format "%c" c))) '(27 91 49 59 51 68)) ; ^[[1;3D
(mapc '(lambda (c) (insert (format "%c" c))) '(27 91 49 59 52 68)) ; ^[[1;4D
```

However, I don't understand why these sequences are embedded in a second-level inner `(keymap ...)` list?!

It gets weirder.

Back in `*scratch*`, when I type

```
M-x local-set-key
```

and then <kbd>M-S-<left></kbd>, it gets recognized correctly, as the next prompt in the minibuffer reveals:

```
Set key <M-S-left> locally to command:
```

If I proceed and provide a random function, say, `beginning-of-line`, a subsequent invocation of <kbd>C-h k</kbd> followed by <kbd>M-S-<left></kbd> then indeed gives:

> <M-S-left> runs the command beginning-of-line (found in
>   lisp-interaction-mode-map), which is an interactive built-in function
>   in ‘C source code’.
>
> It is bound to <M-S-left>.
>
> [...]

Locally setting <kbd>M-S-<left></kbd> to `nil` will restore the initial behavior in which <kbd>C-h k</kbd> reports <kbd>M-S-<left></kbd> as `<M-left>`.

What is going on here? Is this a configuration issue, or is it intended behavior, or are some other keymaps involved that transparently add another layer of remapping?

Comment: Which version of Emacs is this?  For me, Emacs 26.1 reports `<M-left> (translated from <M-S-left>) runs the command left-word`.  You are presumably seeing the same behaviour without being told explicitly that it's a translated sequence.

Comment: GNU Emacs 25.2.2

Comment: FYI I've just tested in 25.3 (which IIRC was only a security patch on top of 25.2), and I see the "translated from" text there as well.  I feel that it's been there for a long time (maybe ever since the shift-translation feature was introduced), so I'm still a bit mystified as to why you're not seeing that yourself.

Comment: I do seem to remember seeing "translated from" messages myself in the past (older Emacs versions). That was the reason why I quoted the first couple of lines of the output I get because there's obviously no mention of it in my version.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51995/454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elisp-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `shift-translation` says:

> If an input character is upper-case (or has the shift modifier) and
>   has no key binding, but its lower-case equivalent has one, then
>   ‘read-key-sequence’ converts the character to lower case.  Note that
>   ‘lookup-key’ does not perform case conversion in this way.
>
> When reading input results in such a “shift-translation”, Emacs sets
>   the variable ‘this-command-keys-shift-translated’ to a non-‘nil’ value.
>   Lisp programs can examine this variable if they need to modify their
>   behavior when invoked by shift-translated keys.  For example, the
>   function ‘handle-shift-selection’ examines the value of this variable to
>   determine how to activate or deactivate the region (*note
>   handle-shift-selection: The Mark.).

Comment: Thanks so much. The `(translated from <M-S-left>)` message that you get in newer Emacs would have solved the problem for me, too, I guess. Coming to think of it, it's kind of an idiotic "feature" - unless I happen to hit Shift by accident, there's probably a reason I did not type the "lower-case" version of the keyboard shortcut. It's also not consistent: on my keyboard, `+` is the the same as `S-=`, but when i `(global-set-key "+" nil)` I get "+ is undefined" in the minibuffer rather than a `=` being inserted.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is precisely correct, but you can probably interpret it as "shift-translation affects the letters A-Z and also keys which do not already have a shift behaviour".

Comment: See also `shift-select-mode` if you haven't already -- I don't use it, but I *think* that is why this feature exists in the first place.

Comment: Wrt your last comment, @phils: No. I'm pretty sure this behavior is old, and `shift-select-mode` is relatively recent. And yes, it was originally about letters - thought to be a convenience by making the Shift key irrelevant for letter-key bindings, by default.